# Animation stops when changing text on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a text area which copies the content to another div. That div though, has text with animation. When I start writing on the textarea and it starts copying to the div, the animations stops. How can I apply an animation with each character input? The animation is applied to the div through the class name.
HTML:

```js
var $tlt = $('.tlt').textillate({ 
    in: {
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        shuffle: true
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOut',
        shuffle: true
    },
    loop: true,
    minDisplayTime: 1000,
});



$('.content:not(.focus)').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.' + contentAttr + '').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>'));
  
})


$(".manifestoWriter").on('change', '#toChange', function(){
   $tlt.textillate('start');
});
```

```html
<textarea id="manifestoWriter" class="chatinput form-control content" placeholder="We want courage, audacity and hope without the fascism" rows="11" style="resize: none; background-color:#f7f7f7; border: 0cm; border-radius: 0cm; " maxlength="800" name="mas"></textarea>

<h1 class="tlt mas" id="toChange">
 We want courage, audacity and hope without the fascism
</h1>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zr1teknf/48/)

Comment: Your code doesn't run because you haven't included JQuery and whatever extension `textillate` comes from

Comment: @zfrisch so sorry, the jsfiddle is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should change textillate.js code. First go to line 247 (or maybe 249) in jquery.textillate.js (you have to download the file). you will find

```
  if (!data) {
    $this.data('textillate', (data = new Textillate(this, options)));
  } else if (typeof settings == 'string') {
    data[settings].apply(data, [].concat(args));
  } else {
    data.setOptions.call(data, options);
  }
```

change it to

```
$this.data('textillate', (data = new Textillate(this, options)));
```

and

```
    $(".manifestoWriter").on('change', '#toChange', function(){
      $tlt.textillate('start');
   });
```

to

```
$("#manifestoWriter").on('change', function(){
       $('.tlt').textillate({ 
        in: {
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        shuffle: true
      },
      out: {
        effect: 'fadeOut',
        shuffle: true
      },
      loop: true,
      minDisplayTime: 1000,
    });
});
```

Check it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr1teknf/111/)

PS: not the best thing to do. if you use "stop" or pass any string to `textillate` it will result in bags

Comment: that stops all animation and for some reason doesn't copy the content on the text area to the <h1>.  got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Textillate wasn't really built with this use case in mind. It was built to help animate lists of sentences like what you see on https://textillate.js.org.

I think you'll be better off using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) directly with some javascript to copy characters from a textarea to another container.

Here's an example to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/jschr/jdqpxyvm/31.

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

const createSpan = (char) => {
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.classList.add('fadeIn')
  span.classList.add('animated')
  span.innerText = char
  return span
}

const updateChars = () => {
  const updatedChars = []
  const currentSpans = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('span'))
  const chars = textarea.value.split('')
  // Iterate over each character in the textarea and append 
  // new chars to the container.
  chars.forEach((char, index) => {
    const spanAtIndex = currentSpans[index]
    // Add new span if one doesn't exist at current index
    if (!spanAtIndex) {
      container.appendChild(createSpan(char))
    }
    // TODO: Handle deletions
  })
}

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  setTimeout(updateChars)
}, false)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! This is actually what i wanted from the beginning!